# how to pass a hours/minutes/datatime as input for a function in python

Tags: python, pandas, time

I want to pass as input of my function a data time in order to select a precise time range to create a time mask.
At the moment, I've tried this way

```
#name is the column where the data are

def mask (hour1, hour2, min1,min2, data1, data2, name):
   timemask=(
   (pd.Timestamp(data1).date() >= df[name].dt.date) &\
    (df[name].dt.date <= pd.Timestamp(data2).date()) &

   (df[name].dt.hour >= hour1) & (df[name].dt.minute >= min1) &\
           (df[name].dt.hour < hour2) & (df[name].dt.minute < min2)
   )
   df1=df[timemask]
   return df1
```

but it's not working and I don't know if I'm passing the values correctly.

Comment: if i run the code with `df["name"]`, i obtain a key error

Comment: Can you provide some entry examples of the data to clarify what you really want with that function? Also, could you add the error that you are getting?

Comment: I have a dataset with a series of dates and times and I want to take a range of these based on the days and times. My database is like

`2021-05-01 00:05

2021-05-01 00:10
...

2021-06-25 23:55`

and I am interested in taking a specific time interval (like all the rows that satisfy the condition 2021-05-10 to 2021-05-25 from 10:30 to 12:00  )because then I will need it for writing some values. 
Using your solution, the error is `KeyError: 'name' `

Comment: Is "name" the real name of your target column?

Comment: nope, it's `TIME`

Comment: given the `KeyError: 'name'` error, you may have run `df["name"]`. you should run `df["TIME"]` instead (or call the function with "TIME" as the last argument)

Comment: @sara-camp I have added a possible solution, but considering data1 and data2 values as input dates. Please check the full example and all the input values.

Comment: You can check data type with df.dtypes (object or datetime?)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the following example, you need to convert your time column to pandas datetime format with `df['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'])`, in this case I named it `col1` but you would write your time column name.

In the mask function, 4 dates are created; 2 for date checking and other 2 for time checking. The last 2 need to use the `replace` function to insert the input parameters of the `mask` function. Essentially, the function is traversing the time column with a for loop because the important result here is the `timemask` list of booleans, so with a `for` you will have access to each value:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import random

datelist = pd.date_range(datetime.today(), periods=100).tolist()
hourlist = [f"{random.randint(0, 24)}:{random.randint(0, 60)}" for i in range(100)]

def mask (hour1, hour2, min1,min2, data1, data2, name):
   data1 = datetime.strptime(data1, '%Y-%m-%d')
   data2 = datetime.strptime(data2, '%Y-%m-%d')

   timemask = []
   for i in df[name]:
      data3, data4 = i, i
      data3 = data3.replace(hour=hour1, minute=min1, second=0)
      data4 = data4.replace(hour=hour2, minute=min2, second=0)

      if ((i > data1 and i <= data2) and (i > data3 and i <= data4)):
         timemask.append(True)
      else:
         timemask.append(False)

   df1=df.loc[timemask]
   return df1

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': datelist, 'col2': hourlist, 'col3': list(range(100))})
df['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'])

print(df, "\n")
print(mask(10, 21, 0, 40, "2022-04-30", "2022-05-05", "col1"))
```